# How can I add auto-renew to an existing membership?

Tags: civimember, stripe, auto-renew

If I have a member sign up for a membership, but neglect to select auto-renew, yet that was the intention, how can I go after the fact and put them on auto-renew?

We are using stripe. I see in stripe that I can create a subscription for the member, but I am unsure if that is the correct method. If I do that, will stripe know to call the hook back to civi so the membership end date will be updated and the contribution recorded created?